# JBuilder template never gets called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `API::V1::ClustersController` structured like so:

```
class Api::V1::ClustersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @clusters = Cluster.all

    render json: @clusters
  end
class
```

In my `app/views/api/v1/clusters/index.json.jbuilder` view:

```
json.array!(@clusters) do |cluster|
  json.extract! cluster, :id, :index
  json.url cluster_url(cluster, format: :json)
end
```

In my routes:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    authenticated :user do
      resources :clusters
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the following is the json output when I hit `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/clusters.json` :

```
{
  clusters: [
    {
      id: 1,
      organization: null,
      number: null,
      name: "Roob Group",
      created_at: "2014-07-16T17:41:09.214Z",
      updated_at: "2014-07-16T17:41:09.214Z"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      organization: null,
      number: null,
      name: "Lesch LLC",
      created_at: "2014-07-16T17:41:09.302Z",
      updated_at: "2014-07-16T17:41:09.302Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know what else to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you need to use `respond_with` instead of `render` in you controller

```
class Api::V1::ClustersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @clusters = Cluster.all

    respond_with @clusters
  end
end
```

When you call `render json: @clusters` its like you call `render @clusters.to_json` so your controller doesn't render a template. if you want to use `render` you can include this in a `respond_to` block, but respond_with is more elegant.

Comment: You also don't have to call `render` or `respond_with`. Thanks for the  help though!

Comment: respond_to and respond_with have been removed in Rails 4.2. My workaround was to do what @KurtMueller suggested: simply remove the call to render.