# Rails4 Jbuilder templates not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I am trying to setup a simple JSON response using Jbuilder.  My controller is as follows:

```
class Api::V1::JobsController < Api::V1::BaseController
   def show
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

I have a jbuilder template here:

`views\api\v1\jobs\show.json.jbuilder`

For some reason when loading the page in a browser or Postman the controller is hit, but the jbuilder template is not found.  I get a:

`Rendered text template (0.5ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 298ms`

If I modify the show action on the jobs controller and add a `render json: @job` I get the desired output, but of course it isn't using the jbuilder template.

Can't figure out why it isn't seeing the jbuilder template!

added some addition details if I go to the .json url

```
Started GET "/api/v1/jobs/69407.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-21 19:16:44 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::JobsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"69407"}
  Job Load (18.3ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 69407]]
  Rendered text template (0.5ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 86ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 56.4ms)
```

update - I have found that if I specifically reference the jbuilder template it loads:

`render 'show', formats: [:json], handlers: [:jbuilder], status: 200`

Also - in order to even get the above to work, I had to add the jbuilder gem to my gem file - which is odd as I am on Rails 4 which should include it by default?

Comment: `Completed 404 Not Found` does not mean that view is not found! If Rails can't find a view it will raise an error and return 500. 404 means that `Job.find(params[:id])` is not finding a record. Check the rails log.

Comment: But it is finding the job, as I said if I add a straight JSON output to the controller `render json: @job` I get the desired JSON out put.

Comment: Can you test accessing `\api\v1\jobs\1.json` and then add the output from the rails log to the question? It makes it much easier to give a qualified answer.

Comment: @max added - thanks!

Comment: @cman77 do you have a respond_to :json in your application controller or base controller? The default is html and I see a rendered text template.

Comment: and what is in routes? `format: 'json'`? Check also [JBuilder template never gets called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795090/jbuilder-template-never-gets-called)

Comment: @OlalekanSogunle duh - I think that was it.  Please answer and I will award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is that you might have to put a `respond_to :json` in your application controller or base controller. The default is html and I see a rendered text template.

Comment: an example wold have sufficed.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @OlalekanSogunle's answer. You can set how you want the action to respond in a couple different ways.

**In the routes** *(this will default the actual routes to set the header request to format json)*:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    namespace :api do
        namespace :v1 do
            get 'jobs/show', to: 'jobs#show', defaults: { format: :json }, as: :job
        end
    end

end
```

**In the Controller as a class default**:

```
class Api::V1::JobsController < Api::V1::BaseController

   respond_to :json

   def show
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
   end

end
```

**In the Controller as an action default**:

```
class Api::V1::JobsController < Api::V1::BaseController

   def show
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
         format.json
      end
   end

end
```